# Как остановить linux (ubuntu) процесс с консоли Putty

Tags: linux, ubuntu, putty

Запустил свой Java процесс с консоли Putty.

```
javac project.java
java project
```

И чтобы его завершить нажимаю CTRL+C, все бы хорошо, но Putty случайно закрылась, а java процесс не остановился и как теперь его завершить?

Comment: какая ОС на сервере?

Comment: на сервере ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

**Для Linux:**

Сначала нужно найти `pid` процесса:

```
ps -aux | grep "java project"
```

Потом использовать `kill` для завершения процесса

```
kill <pid>
```

Где `<pid>` это найденный выше идентификатор.

**Для Windows**

Находим `pid` процесса:

```
tasklist /fi "ImageName eq java.exe"
```

Завершаем процесс:

```
taskkill /pid <pid>
```

Для Windows есть один неприятный нюанс, `tasklist.exe` не показывает параметры командной строки, поэтому придётся угадать, если процессов несколько

Comment: `sudo killall java` тоже можно, если нет других нужных запущенных приложений, я думаю :)

Comment: killall это уже оружие массового поражения, я всё же за точечные удары.

Comment: `pkill`, `pgrep` -- более корректные для многопоточных программ.